# Run Laravel CRON scheduler at multiple intervals

Tags: laravel, cron, schedule

I have a particular function in my Laravel app I want to trigger daily at 1 am, 9 am, 1 pm and 6 am.

I tried to create a separate schedule for the same command 2 times.

```php
$schedule->command('command:commandname')->twiceDaily(1, 9);
$schedule->command('command:commandname')->twiceDaily(13, 18);
```

But this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `->at()`:

```
$schedule->command('command:commandname')
    ->at('01:00')
    ->at('09:00')
    ->at('13:00')
    ->at('18:00');
```

Comment: Using this ran only the last chained ->at().

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cron()` method to specify this as a custom schedule:

```
$schedule->command('command:commandname')->cron('0 1,9,13,18 * * *');
```

You could also have it run hourly and have the command's code return early if the hour isn't one of your four.

```
public function handle() {
    if(!in_array(now()->hour, [1, 9, 13, 18])) {
        return;
    }

    // the rest of your command
}
```

(You'd want to be a little careful with this approach. If other jobs run more than an hour before this job runs, it could push its execution into the *next* hour, which would wind up skipping it. Unlikely, but something to consider.)